# Magento 2.4.5 upgrade error: Could not find a magento/project package matching "magento/magento-cloud-metapackage 2.4.5"

Tags: magento2, upgrade, security-patch

While upgrading Magento Enterprise version from 2.4.5-p4 to 2.4.5-p5, i get the following error on running **composer require-commerce magento/product-enterprise-edition=2.4.5-p5 --no-update --force-root-updates**

*Could not find a magento/project package matching "magento/magento-cloud-metapackage 2.4.5"*

FYI : I already ran the command **composer require magento/composer-root-update-plugin:'*'** before upgrade.

Any help to fix the issue would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any luck? on the same we are also facing same!!

Answer (score 0):

Because you are accessing private package (Magento EE)

```
composer config --global http-basic.repo.magento.com <public_key> <private_key>
```

Image how key look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYhJE.png

use this before installing the Magento app

Thanks

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, doesnt work. same error.